# Executing insert on MySQL, no error but also no insert

Tags: python, mysql

Note: I am quite new to Python so the problem could be anything.

- Python: 3.6
- MySQL: 8

I have a MySQL database setup and can successfully query from it through Python, so I am sure my connection is OK. I can insert records inside MySQL Workbench, so I am fairly sure the DB is OK. However, when I run the following code, I get no error ("Done" does print, "error" does not print). However, the record is not being inserted.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='furby',
    password='something',host='127.0.0.1', database='mydb')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

document_root = ET.fromstring(semester.read('data'))
semester_name = document_root.get("Name")
print(semester_name)
query = ("SELECT semester_id 
    FROM StudentData.semesters 
    WHERE name = '%s'")
cursor.execute(query % semester_name)
cursor.fetchall()
print(cursor.rowcount)
if (cursor.rowcount == 0):
    print("hi")
    start_date = document_root.get("StartDate")
    end_date = document_root.get("EndDate")
    notes = document_root.get("Notes")
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO StudentData.semesters 
            (name, start_date, end_date, notes) VALUES 
            ('" + semester_name + "', '" + start_date + "', 
            '" + end_date + "', '" + notes + "')"
        print(query)
        cursor.execute(query)
    except:
        print("error")

    print("done")
```

I had gotten lots of errors building up to this but suddenly, no errors. However, there must be some error, right?

What am I doing wrong here that would stop the record from being inserted without generating any kind of error?

**Edit**
After Douglas's answer, I changed to print the SQL insert statement and then copy and pasted it into SQL Workbench. Again, it does nothing running it through python but running in SQL Workbench does insert the record as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you should close your cursor. And your connection is autocommited?
Plese check it, and you should commit it!

Comment: Thanks Laszlo but if I close the cursor then I cannot execute against it. If I close and reopen I still get the same result (no error but no record being inserted)

Comment: Ok and the transaction? Did you have commited?

Comment: That was it! I did not realize this detail but it now works perfectly.

Comment: Super! Nice day

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obvious, though I have a suggestion.
The same way you created the query above before executing it,
do the same below and print it before execution so you can be sure 
what you are executing. As a general rule I don't construct query
strings within the execute function. I don't see a close which might
have helped commit the data. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did make the change as you suggested but it does not help (see edit in question)